# Run rspec on VS Code

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

I have rspec test code like this

```
describe 'Utils' do

  puts 1111
  describe '#time_condition' do
    puts 2221
    it do
      puts 'aaa'
    end
    puts 2223
  end
end
```

my launch.json like this

```
{
  "name": "RSpec - all",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/spec/*_rspec.rb",
  "args": [
    "--pattern",
    "*_rspec.rb"
  ]
},
```

when I run test on vscode, I got

```
1111
2221
2223
```

when I run test by command, got

```
>rspec spec --pattern *_rspec.rb
1111
2221
2223
aaa
.

Finished in 0.003 seconds (files took 0.23602 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

As your can see, no 'aaa' output, means no 'it' was executed.
So...How can I make 'it' to run on vscode?

by the way, my spec config files (generated by rspec --init)like

.rspec

```
--color
--require spec_helper
```

spec\spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.profile_examples = 10

  config.order = :random

  Kernel.srand config.seed
end
```

VScode : 1.4.0

Ruby Extensions : 0.5.3

thanks

Comment: I cannot see your expects in your rspec file

Comment: @Bustikiller Just deleted. 'it' can't run no matter have expects or not.

Comment: try using the syntax `it 'test name' do` instead

Comment: @Bustikiller Would not and did not work. As I wrote, rspec command succeed. So my rspec codes are fine. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I solved it!
My fault is setting wrong value to program.
Program must be rspec path.

```
...
{
  "name": "RSpec - all",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "program": "D:/Ruby/Ruby21/bin/rspec",
  "args": [
    "--pattern",
    "${workspaceRoot}/spec/**/*_rspec.rb"
  ]
},
...
```

Comment: How do you invoke this?

Comment: Just like the others, select "RSpec - all" , and click start debugging. BTW, I'm not playing RSpec for a long while.

Answer (score 14):

Finally got RSpec to run on VS Code, with **breakpoints**, on a Mac! No one at my startup knew how. See Microsoft's handy [GitHub page on it](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-Ruby-on-Rails).

My `Gemfile`. Install 3 gems:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rspec'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
gem 'debase'
```

My `launch.json`:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Run RSpec - all",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "program": "/Users/[your name]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rspec",
      "args": [
        "--pattern",
        "${workspaceRoot}/spec/**/*_spec.rb"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Debug RSpec - open spec file",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "useBundler": true,
      "pathToBundler": "/Users/[your name]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/bundle",
      "pathToRDebugIDE": "/Users/[your name]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rdebug-ide",
      "debuggerPort": "1235",
      "program": "/Users/[your name]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rspec",
      "args": [
        "${file}"
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

For "program", use value of `which rspec`. My path assumes I installed Ruby with RVM. Yours will be different.

For "pathToBundler", use value of `which bundle`

For "pathToRDebugIDE", use value of `which rdebug-ide`

For this line: `"${workspaceRoot}/spec/**/*_spec.rb"`, yours may differ, depending how your spec files are organized, by folder.

**To run RSpec:**

In VS Code, go to `Terminal -> New Terminal` in top menu. Be sure you're in root directory of your Ruby project.

Click left of any line number to **set breakpoints**, if you like.

Click Bug icon on left side of VS Code. Pick configuration from dropdown box in upper left:

1. `Debug RSpec - open spec file` or
2. `Run RSpec - all`

Then click green triangle (`Start Debugging`) on upper left.

**Even easier:** install VS Code Extension [Rails Test Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidpallinder.rails-test-runner). Then right-click on your spec file to either:

1. `Run all tests in file` or
2. `Run tests starting from the current line`

Comment: Got this working with WSL on Windows as well. Nice!

Comment: What if you dont want it in your gemfile? I tried doing gem install ruby-debug-ide , set useBundler to false and editied the path but it didnt work

Comment: To install Gems, for your Ruby project, you must put them in your Gemfile. If you don't want these Gems in production, put them in a 

`group :test, :development do` block.

Comment: This still works in 2022, however, make sure to replace `2.6.4` with the version of ruby installed on your machine.

Comment: When working in a DevContainer use `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rspec"`, and create a binstub for rspec.

Answer (score 4):

Here is `version: 2.0.0` for Linux

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "rspec - all",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "$(which bundle) exec rspec",
      "group": "test",
    },
    {
      "label": "rspec - one file",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "$(which bundle) exec rspec ${file}",
      "group": "test",
    },
    {
      "label": "rspec - focus",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "$(which bundle) exec rspec ${file} --focus",
      "group": "test",
    }

  ]
}
```

Now run `Ctrl+Shift+p` and in menu: `Tasks: ...`

Comment: Thanks I'll check this. I struggle a lot to configure this out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution than using local path in the debugger configuration. in `launch.json`

```
  {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "RSpec - all",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rspec",
            "args": [
                "-I",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ]
        }
      ]
   }
```

In this example you call the rspec binstub in the `bin` folder referenced by the `${workspaceRoot}` variable. Now you can also share the configuration as-is with other people working on the project.
If you don't have the bin folder with the binstub you can generate one by executing:

```
bundle binstubs rspec-core
```

See: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-binstubs.1.html

Answer (score 1):

This I believe is the simplest configuration that should work for every case. It runs the current open file but you can tweak it so it runs all rspec files.

```json
{
  "name": "RSpec",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/bundle",
  "args": [
    "exec",
    "rspec",
    "${file}"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project has `rspec` in its `bin` folder, you can try the following:

```
{
  "name": "RSpec - all",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rspec",
  "args": [
    "-I",
    "${workspaceRoot}"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using the [debug](https://github.com/ruby/debug) gem. Seems to be quite straightforward and future proof.

Install the gem and this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KoichiSasada.vscode-rdbg

In `launch.json` I use a current line `rspec` call:

```
{
  "type": "rdbg",
  "name": "Run rake spec",
  "request": "launch",
  "command": "bundle exec rspec",
  "script": "${file}:${lineNumber}",
  "args": [],
  "askParameters": false
}
```

I haven't tested this extensively but haven't had any issues yet on Ruby 3.0.2