# Run Rspec block via hot key in VS Code

Tags: rspec, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure VS Code to run an Rspec block in the current cursor position?

Either a `describe` or `it` block.

I found similar functionality through Atom with the Rspec extension. A hot key became available `Cmd + alt + X`. Which would trigger the single `it` or a group within `describe` depending where the cursor was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=noku.rails-run-spec-vscode

And then press `Cmd + L` to run the specific `describe` or `it`

Answer (score 0):

I installed [Rails Test Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidpallinder.rails-test-runner). Open your spec file, put your cursor on/in the `describe` or `it` block, then right click. You see 2 choices:

1. Run all tests in file
2. Run tests starting from the current line

To set up RSpec to run in VS Code, with breakpoints, [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104979/2175188).