# Breakpoint not working on VScode for Rspec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, rspec-rails, ruby-debug-ide

Not sure what's wrong with my setup. I've been stuck on this issue for a day now and still hasn't resolved this. I've setup my VScode so I can debug my specs (for Ruby on Rails) faster. I followed this [guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-Ruby-on-Rails) on Github, originally stumbled upon this Stackoverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284637/run-rspec-on-vs-code).

I've added [ruby-debug-ide](https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide) & debase under the development and test group in my gem file & execute `$ bundle install`. They seem to be working ok (I think) based on what I can see on my debug console.

**Gemfile:**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
  gem 'debase'
end
```

**Debug console:**

This is how it looks like after pressing F5 or clicking the "Run" button under the Run & Debug tab on VSCode.

[image]

Looking at this part of the debug console I know that my spec file is being executed properly:

[image]

**Launch.json file:**

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug RSpec - open spec file",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "useBundler": true,
      "pathToBundler": "/Users/<my computer name>/.rbenv/shims/bundle",
      "pathToRDebugIDE": "/Users/<my computer name>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.3",
      "debuggerPort": "1235",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rspec",
      "args": [
        "${file}"
      ],
      "showDebuggerOutput": true
    },
  ]
}
```

I've added a breakpoint on my spec file (even tried adding multiple breakpoints) but it's debugger isn't hitting any of it. Made sure it's turned on (See screenshot below).

[image]

**Other info about my setup that might help, tell me if you need more info:**

- Machine is MBP 2021 Intel
- OS: Mac OS Monterey 12.0.1
- Latest version of VSCode installed
- Ruby version: ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-darwin20
- Rails version: Rails 5.2.3
- Version manager: RBenv

Answer (score 0):

This configuration where working for me:

```
{
  "name": "Start rails server",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/rails",
  "useBundler": true,
  "pathToBundler": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/bundle",
  "showDebuggerOutput": true,
  "pathToRDebugIDE": "/${workspaceFolder}/bin/rdebug-ide",
  "args": ["s"]
},
{
  "name": "Run tests",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/rspec",
  "useBundler": true,
  "pathToBundler": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/bundle",
  "showDebuggerOutput": true,
  "pathToRDebugIDE": "/${workspaceFolder}/bin/rdebug-ide",
  "args": []
},
{
  "name": "Run single test file",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/rspec",
  "useBundler": true,
  "pathToBundler": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/bundle",
  "showDebuggerOutput": true,
  "pathToRDebugIDE": "/${workspaceFolder}/bin/rdebug-ide",
  "args": [
    "-I",
    "${workspaceRoot}",
    "${file}"
  ]
},
```

It made them work based on this [blog post](https://dev.to/abstractart/easy-way-to-setup-debugger-and-autocomplete-for-ruby-in-visual-studio-code-2gcc)

But I've also realized that You don't need:

```
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
  gem 'debase'
```

and new implementation for [debugger](https://github.com/ruby/debug) is  working